# How set up arelle for large xbrl files?

Tags: python, xbrl, arelle

[Here](https://github.com/C-h-e-r-r-y/arelle-web-service) is a github repository to reproduce the issue.

A main problem is memory Arelle memory usage. Even small files (AppropriationsAccountPackage.xbrl - 46Mb) take about 7+Gb RAM memory and failed to proces (bith import to postgers or view file in rest).

Is there a way to optimize arelle memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

I did not figured out what issue was, but updating from python `3.5` to python `3.7.5` fixed the problem.

E.g. dockerfile should be started with:

FROM python:3.7.5-alpine